# How to integrate URI parameter with Form Data validation in Play framework 2.x?

Tags: validation, scala, playframework-2.0

For example, I have a route like this:

```
PUT           /bob/:id           controllers.BobController.update(id: String)
```

The BobController:

```
object BobController extends Controller {

    case class BobForm(status: Int)

    val bobForm = Form(
        mapping(
            "status" -> number(min = -11, max = 99)
        )(BobForm.apply)(BobForm.unapply)
    )

    def update(id: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
        bobForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
            formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.bob(formWithErrors)),
            formBob =>
                if (id.trim.nonEmpty) {
                    val bob = Bob.update(id, formBob.status)
                    Redirect(routes.Application.showBob(bob.id)).flashing("success" -> "Bob saved!")
                } else {
                    BadRequest(views.html.bob(formBob, "ID is invalid"))
                }
        )
    }
}
```

You can see at this line I have to do a manual validation of `id` not to be blank value:

```
if (id.trim.nonEmpty) {
```

I would like to have the `id` validation incorporated into the Form mapping instead:

```
    case class BobForm(id: String, status: Int)

    val bobForm = Form(
        mapping(
            "id" -> nonEmptyText,
            "status" -> number(min = -11, max = 99)
        )(BobForm.apply)(BobForm.unapply)
    )
```

But if I do that, the `bobForm.bindFromRequest` will fail because `id` parameter is not in request's form data.

So is there a way to integrate URI parameter like the `id` with Play's Form data validation?